# Nesting Content in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am building a Travel App which will have the following Structure

Collections
Places
Categories

At Time one place will have many places associated to it. It can be a Region like for example

Coorg which has many place in Coorg like Talakaveri, Brahmagiri Hills

I have the following structure for places

```
[
    {
        "_id": "PLACE-ID",
        "name": "",
        "slug": "",
        "decription": "",
        "display_photo": [
            {
                "title": "",
                "file": "",
                "credit": ""
            }
        ],
        "location": [
            {
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "country": "",
                "coordinates": ["<longitude> ", "<latitude>"]
            }
        ],
        "categories": ["", ""]
    }
]
```

Which is the best way to add the linking of parent or child place inside when necessary? Do i need to insert the `_id` or need to have another collection that stores these relations.

Comment: Trying to use a non-relational database as a relational database is going to lead to pain. Why don't you use a relational database - MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: @ceejayoz bcos going forward am certain mondoDB will add an advantage. Which is the best way to store relations between two locations in the same collections?

Comment: Why are you so certain? You're not using MongoDB for a MongoDB-friendly use case here. There's a reason even huge companies like Google and Facebook use relational databases for some things.

Comment: @ceejayoz i totally agree. my app will be modeled towards foursquare where the data is very unstructured. even places will have many uncommon elements. hence we decided on the same

Comment: What's best would be determined on far more factors than can be considered on Stackoverflow. Have a look at the data modeling guidelines: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-models/. Try some models, do a LOT of performance testing to validate.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of your schema design is to think about your data usage patterns. Special consideration is required for:

1. How are you going to access and display the data.
2. What are the document and sub-document properties that you need to query/filter on in combination

For best application performance you are aiming for as little over the wire traffic as possible, so the ultimate goal is to be able to get your information and write things back with as little requests as possible. Preferably 1 each way.

Try and get as much useful information into 1 document as possible and only go to references when you have to.

Comment: You definitely want your data model to efficiently support your usage patterns, but I would stress that the goal isn't always to get everything into a single document. Documents that grow frequently (or have unbounded growth) are a definite anti-pattern for performance; documents with highly nested structures can also be inefficient to query or update. There is a good section on [Data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) in the MongoDB manual that covers some concepts, considerations, and patterns.